# gmdistribution for classification in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let's assume I have two gmdistibution models that i obtained using

```
modeldata1=gmdistribution.fit(data1,1);
modeldata2=gmdistribution.fit(data2,1);
```

Now I have an unknown 'data' observation, and I want to see if it belongs to `data1` or `data2`.

Based on my understanding of these functions, nlogn output using posterior,cluster, or pdf commands wouldn't be a good measure since I am comparing 'data' to two different distributions.

What measure or output should I use find what is the `p(data|modeldata1) and p(data|modeldata2)` ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to assign a new, unknown, datapoint to either class 1 or class 2 with the descriptors for each class (in this case the mean vector and covariance matrix) found by gmdistribution.fit.

In seeing this new datapoint, lets call it x, you should ask yourself what is
p(modeldata1 | x) and p(modeldata2 | x) and which ever one of these is the highest you should assign x to.

So how do you find these? You just apply Bayes rule and pick which ever one is the largest of:

```
p(modeldata1 | x) = p(x|modeldata1)p(modeldata1)/p(x)
p(modeldata1 | x) = p(x|modeldata2)p(modeldata2)/p(x)
```

Here you dont need to calculate p(x) as it is the same in each equation.

So, now you estimate the priors p(modeldata1) and p(modeldata2) by the number of training points from each class (or use some given information) and then calculate

```
p(x|modeldata1)=1/((2pi)^d/2 * sqrt(det(Sigma1)))*exp(0.5*(x-mu1)/Sigma1*(x-mu1))
```

where `d` is the dimensionality of your data, `Sigma` is a corvariance matrix, and `mu` is a mean vector. This is then your asked for p(data|modeldata1). (Just remember to also use p(modeldata1) and p(modeldata2) when you do the classification).

I know this was a bit unclear, but hopefully it can help you with a step in the right direction.

EDIT: Personally, I find a visualization such as the one below (takes from Pattern Recognition by Theodoridis and Koutroumbas). Here you have two gaussian mixtures with some priors and different covariance matrices. The blue area is where you would choose one class, while the gray area is where the other would be choosen. [image]

Comment: Correct, but the thing is, I can find the likelihood ( or more specifically nlogliklihood ) with matlab itself. However, these number are not really making sence to me. It seems they need some normalization that I am unable to figure out.

Comment: How do you mean? What range of numbers are you typically getting? Keep in mind that you can not expect the p(x|y) (a probability distribution) to lie in [0, 1] in the continuous case.

Comment: If I assume the prior p(modeldata1)=p(modeldata2), and p(x) wouldn't matter as it will only have same effect on p(modeldata1|x) and p(modeldata2|x). Then can I base my decision on the the nlogn ?   I think your point is exactly my confusion. P(x|y) doesn't have to be [0 to 1] but it is the still the case if (p1|x)>(p2|x) then I have higher probability that to choose p1 over p2 right ? ( I hope I delivered my point)

Comment: My problem is, I am getting the theory behind it but I am having a better decision using a simple threshold than a gmm model. So i am pulling my hair for the past two days trying to see how is that possible.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the somewhat late reply. I'm not sure I follow exactly, but maybe your problem is that you have gotten fixated on "the probability of choosing p1" - you should rather use this evaluation to make a strict decision rule; i. e. "I choose model1 whenever p(model1|x) > p(model2|x)". Dont get bogged down with specifics regarding what this "means", just acknowledged that it might be a good rule to follow